# How to resize a frame in Tcl / Tk

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

How do i disable a frame in Tcl / Tk

I have tried:

```
ttk::frame .container;
wm resizable .container 0 0
```

but it doesn't work. It says it is not a top level container. And when i tried the same thing using:

```
toplevel .container
wm resizable .container 0 0
```

This worked. But that is not what i want. I would like to disable a frame that is not a top level container.

Comment: Do you want to resize or disable the frame?

Comment: @luchosrock I want the maximize button button of the frame disabled

Comment: Any reason why you want it to be disabled? And could you put a link to a picture of your 'frame', because I don't have any maximize button on the frame when I create one.

Comment: "Disable a frame" makes no sense. Frames can't be enabled or disabled. Either they exist or they don't. Are you wanting to disable all widgets inside a frame?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

First create a toplevel window...

```
% set tl [toplevel .someNameOrOther]
```

...and a frame in that toplevel...

```
% set frm [ttk::frame $tl.myFrame]
```

...Then pack the frame into the toplevel container...

```
% pack $frm -expand yes -fill both
```

...Set the toplevel container to be non-resizable

```
% wm resizable $tl 0 0
```

...and you're done. The maximize button on the toplevel container that holds your frame is grayed-out.

This should work whether you are using an old-style `frame`, or the newer `ttk::frame`, and whatever geometry manager you use for the toplevel - `grid` or `pack` as above.

Edited to correct typos pointed out by Hoodiecrow

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** You can't do it that way. Try `place`, and understand what disabling propagation in `pack` and `grid` does.

---

Every widget's size (and position) is *totally* at the mercy of its container. For toplevel widgets, the container is (effectively) the window manager, and the `wm` command makes *polite* requests to the window manager for things (this also means that it only applies to toplevel widgets, and probably should have been done via options on the `toplevel`, but that's a boat that was missed decades ago).

For non-toplevels, Tk is in control and it does this via its geometry manager system (unlike some toolkits, Tk doesn't strictly bind each widget to using a single geometry manager). The `pack` and `grid` geometry managers are very keen on resizing widgets to try to produce what is usually a pleasing arrangement, in accordance with the instructions they've been given; each allows propagation to be turned off (you might find this relevant if you're putting content in the frame), which means that they stop resizing the master in response to requested changes to the size of the children, but they still change the children's sizes.

However, the `place` geometry manager can do the sort of thing you're after. With `place`, you control exactly what is going on, directly specifying what the locations and sizes are. Indeed, if you want to do things like propagation, you have to install `<Configure>` events yourself to detect the fact that changes need to occur, and you pretty much have to do all the logic yourself. For a widget whose size doesn't change, simply leave the width and height unspecified when setting up the `place`ing of the widget and all should be OK.

```
ttk::frame .f -width 15 -height 18
place .f -x 30 -y 45
```

Just be aware that it means that you're taking on the responsibility for making things look OK. Most people programming with Tk find it easier to use `grid` or `pack` instead, and just specify the padding on widgets as appropriate.